# Dragger replaced with weight field

Tags: media

i have a image gallery in my website created from nodes, so 1 node is equal to 1 album, each node has all images uploaded .. it seemed to work fine, until - somehow the dragger have been replaced with "weight" when i edit the node/album.
Also, eventhough i have no limit set, it only uploads the first 20 selected pictures, eventhough i select and upload 35 pictures .. i dont know why this happened.

Comment: Try clearing the caches.  Sometimes you will see the "weight" field instead of the dragging widget when Javascript, etc. fails to load properly.

Comment: @Patrick stale js suggests problems with clearing. Deleting sites/*/files/js/* by hand might be needed too.

Comment: thank you both very much, it helped clearing caches on dragging widget .. but i can still only upload 20 pictures at a time which i really don't understand.

Comment: now i cant even upload images at all .. and i did not touch anything

Comment: something happend to the multiupload module , it does not want to upload anymore .. i deleted it and using plupload instead , works much better.